# Check checkbox = Toggle class in div (with many same divs)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of divs (#div1, #div2, #div3 etc). Each one of those divs contain different pictures and texture. The divs share the same layout class and they all contain a checkbox (all checkboxes also have one class).

I want the individual div to toggle class when the checkbox inside it are checked.

How to manage this without all divs toggle class when click a checkbox in one div?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us your HTML, don't describe it at us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4mTfV/2/).

Use the `.click()` for the checkbox and then get its parent div by using `.parent()` then call `.toggleClass('classforparentdiv')`.

**UPDATE**

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4mTfV/5/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: This code worked but I forget to tell that the checkboxes also are in one div so the #div1,2,3 is not the parent div. Sorry I forgot that. <div class="outer_div"><div class="inner_div"><input type="checkbox"></div></div>. Its the #outer_div that I want to toggle class.

Comment: Just call `.parent()` after calling `.parent()`. So your code would look like this: `.parent().parent().toggleClass('classforouter');`

Comment: I tested that but it dident work, it still toggle the parent div.

Comment: I have updated my demo. You can see that the `outer_div`'s color will change upon toggle of checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbin.com/exasow/1/edit

```
$(':checkbox').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('div[id^=div]').toggleClass( 'superclass' );
});
```

you can use both `click` or `change` function.

http://api.jquery.com/closest/ will allow you to have your checkbox inside other elements, it will always search up the DOM tree for the desired parent:

`div[id^=div]` means `DIV element which ID starts with the word "div"` and will work for all your `div1, div2, div***` selectors.

Comment: This code worked but I forget to tell that the checkboxes also are in one div so the #div1,2,3 is not the parent div. Sorry I forgot that. <div class="outer_div"><div class="inner_div"><input type="checkbox"></div></div>. Its the #outer_div that I want to toggle class.

Answer (score 0):

Give a Id to the checkboxes and on basis of that toggle the parent div class

or, listen to the event and toggle the class of the parent div

Something like this,

$(event.currentTarget).parent().toggle('className');